# jQuery WCF Service MVC2 VS2010 .NET 4.0 call with parameters fails

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, wcf

In Visual Studio 2010 I created a new Ajax enabled WCF Service

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "TestWCFAjax.Bridge")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Bridge
{
    [OperationContract]
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "jQuery WCF call without parameters from MVC2 works." ; 
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public string DoWork1(string parm)
    {
        return parm + " jQuery WCF call with parameters from MVC2 fails";
    }
```

In the Home Controllers Index.aspx view I add the jQuery:

function CallWebMethod() {

```
$.ajax(
{
     type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
url: "http://localhost:1452/Bridge.svc/DoWork1",
dataType: "json",
data: '{"parm":"test"}',
error: jqueryError,
success: function (msg) {
     alert("back");
     var divForResult = document.getElementById("test");
     divForResult.innerHTML = "Result: <b>" + msg.d + "</b>";
    }
 })
}

function jqueryError(request, status, error) {
    alert(request.responseText + " " + status + " " + error);
}
```

(using the built-in Web Server in VS 2010)

When I call DoWork, it works fine.
When I call DoWork1 it always returns "error undefined" and the WCF call never happens.

I've tried every combination of:
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
I can think of and it does not help.

I must be missing something simple.

There are MANY posting about how to make this work, and other than the "no parameter" version, none have worked for me.

Can anyone post a sample MVC2 jQuery 1.4 .NET 4.0 WCF VS2010 working sample or spot the likely error?

Thanks.

Comment: how did you configure your base address on the wcf config? Is the Bridge.svc included in it? Is it mandatory to put this? Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",

should be

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: This fixes the problem.  To recap:

To call an Ajax Enabled WCF service using jQuery in a MVC2/.NET 4.0 project, you do NOT need to do any of the following things people suggest:
No Factory="...WebScriptServiceHostFactory" is needed in the .SVC
No [WebInvoke(...)] attribute on the WCF method is needed, just [OperationContract]
No changes in the web.config are needed, no webHttp behavior, no changes to the endpoint or any endpoint behavior other than enableWebScript
No MVC2 IgnoreRoute needed.

Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 0):

I have been [writing and presenting on using jQuery with WCF](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/tags/WCF/default.aspx). The whole MVC does not really matter, or shouldn't matter at least :) I have several post about using it and there is a link for you to download the lastest source from my demo project.